# Analysing wrongly predicted labels and pick most significant

Tags: statistics, anomaly-detection

I try to do behavior analysis of network systems based on network flow. I have a model that predicts if a certain flow pattern is a Windows Server, LX Server or Windows Client. (Highly simplified) I am interested in the flows that were incorrectly predicted.

Since I am predicting based on flows the resulting table has many entries per host. The predicted label for the same host might be different depending on the flow. I have attached a screenshot of how it could look like. System A is there twice for 2 different flows which has been "falsly" predicted.

I am trying to find a good way to compress the table so that there is 1 entry per host with maybe the most significant false predicted label in order to trigger some alert. I probably will require some sort of threshold to minimise the false positives accepting the risk that I might miss some true positives.

[image]